# create only limited number of page in drupal

Tags: drupal, permissions

Is it possible in drupal that I can give permission to user to create only limited number of pages.

For eg.

I want to give user a permission to add only 5 pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a module for that: [Node Limit](http://drupal.org/project/node_limit)

> The Node Limit module allows administrators to restrict the number of nodes of a specific type that roles or users may create.

Comment: great... I will test this and comment back.